# ajax php json returns null

Tags: php, ajax, json

EDIT : The problem was that I tried to call the function the way I might have called a function when using a framework. And, I didn't even bother to mention some very important things such as I'm not using a framework with this one.

As pointed out by my colleague, this here should be able to help out. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

The Problem:
I've tried numerous ways suggested by other users but json still returns NULL or blank. Here is my code and the lines that I've commented out are the ones that I tried but failed. Now I know there had been posts such as mine before but none of those worked for me. Thanks everyone in advance.

EDIT: I'm using chrome and when I F12, goto Network, I can see that the function login() was accessed and the data that I've passed are also there. But, when I tried to print a string and/or die()/exit(), response still gives me 'This request has no data available'. What does this mean?

I've initially tested this out without doing any queries and still returns NULL. I                           guess my question got down voted because there seemed to be an error with my query so I just wanted to clear that out. I've been dealing with this one for 2 days now and I've tried pretty much everything and I'm sure it's not the query.

```
    public static function login()
{
    //      header("Content-Type: application/json");
    //      header("Content-Type: text/javascript");

    $response->msg  = '';
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $hashed = hash('md5', $password);
    $query = mysql_query("select * from tbl_user where username = '$username' and password = '$hashed'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_object($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $response->msg  = 1;
        $response->username = $username;

    //          $response['msg']  = 1;
    //          $response['username'] = $username;

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {
    //          $response['msg']  = 0;
        $response->msg  = 0;
        echo json_encode($username);
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
$("#btn_submit").click(function(){

    var username = $("#txtusername").val();
    var password = $("#mypassword").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'includes/main.php/login',
        data: { username: username,  password: password },
                    type: 'post',
    //          async:false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});


    //  $('#btn_submit').click(function() {
    //      var username = $("#txtusername").val();
    //      var password = $("#mypassword").val();
    //      
    //      $.getJSON(base_url + 'includes/main.php/login', 
    //          { username: username,  password: password },
    //      function(json) {
    //          console.log(json);
    //      });
    //  });


    //  $('#btn_submit').click(function() {
    //      var username = $("#txtusername").val();
    //      var password = $("#mypassword").val();
    //
    //      $.post(base_url + 'includes/main.php/login', 
    //          {username: username,  password: password}, 
    //      function(r) {
    //          console.log(r);
    //      }, "json");
    //  });
```

Comment: have you tried with `header("Content-Type: application/json");` in the php or by removing `dataType: 'json'` in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

I think this not a problem about json. Your code output nothing probably because of an error, and an database error is not generally reported by php explicitly, endyourif's solution's should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand the question, and you did not specify that you have used any frameworks, you were trying to call the php method through the AJAX url

**leave this if the `login()` is a controller method**

```
url: base_url + 'includes/main.php/login',
```

But you cant do this way, try the following

In javascript

```
$("#btn_submit").click(function(){

    var username = $("#txtusername").val();
    var password = $("#mypassword").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'includes/main.php',
        data: { action:'login', username: username,  password: password },
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

In php

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'login') {
    login();
}

function login()
{
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    $response->msg  = '';
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Do the rest ............

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I figured now that I hadn't followed some PHP OOP rules with the way I had called the function. This login() is actually inside a class Main. This is the first time that I'm doing OOP without using a framework hence this problem. I will now stick to using frameworks then maybe later study pure PHP OOP? Anyway, I should delete this thread.

Comment: I'd upvote you because you were close to figuring out where the problem was exactly. But I'd rather not set this as accepted for reasons that this could mislead other people since the problem wasn't on the js part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Might also be issue with AJAX being sent as get causing the PHP script to fail:

```
$.ajax({
    url: base_url + 'includes/main.php/login',
    data: { username: username,  password: password },
//          async:false,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

It looks like you might have an error in your query here:

```
    $query = mysql_query("select * from tbl_user where username = $username and password = $hashed");
```

The $username and $password need to be enclosed in single quotes:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from tbl_user where username = '$username' and password = '$hashed'");
```

I'm guessing the reason you are getting null is an error is being silently generated.

Try adding an or die() after your query:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from tbl_user where username = $username and password = $hashed") or die('Query error');
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot to mention that I've initially tried the code without doing any queries. Thank you for pointing that out but my problem has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It's also quite possible then that you need to set the "type" for your $.ajax to be POST as the default is get. See edit for updated answer for javascript change.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the page even gets called successfully?  E.g. add an echo right at the top then exit();

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, the page and particular function is called successfully. I also receive the values passed. It's just that no matter what value I pass, I will always get NULL